# How to find hidden columns in Telerik Radgridview using Linq expression

Tags: c#, .net, linq, silverlight, telerik-grid

How to find invisible columns from Telerik Radgridview.I tried with following expression

```
RadGridView radGridView = dependencyObject as RadGridView;
var columns = radGridView.Columns.Where(x => x.IsVisible == false);
```

I got following exception

> Error   1   'Telerik.Windows.Controls.GridViewColumnCollection' does not
>   contain a definition for 'Where' and the best extension method
>   overload
>   'Telerik.Windows.Data.QueryableExtensions.Where(System.Linq.IQueryable,
>   Telerik.Windows.Data.FilterDescriptorCollection)' has some invalid
>   arguments

Can anyone help on this

Comment: According to [this](http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/winforms/api/html/p_telerik_wincontrols_ui_radgridview_columns.htm) and [this](http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/winforms/api/html/t_telerik_wincontrols_ui_gridviewcolumncollection.htm), the columns property inherits from ```ObservableCollection``` so you should be able to enumerate over them, did you add ```using System.Linq``` ?

Comment: Yes..Linq is using

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var columns = new List<Telerik.Windows.Controls.GridViewColumn>(gridView.Columns);
var filteredList = columns.Where(o => o.IsVisible == false);
```

Cheers

Comment: Thanks..i will test it